# What query should I use to fix these problems?

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have a table like this:

```
Date   | Expedition Name | Invoice
___________________________________________
4/6/12 | Starsindo       | X001908
4/6/12 | Starsindo       | X001900
4/6/12 | De Ros indah    | X002008
4/6/12 | De Ros indah    | X002108
4/6/12 | De Ros indah    | X002208
4/6/12 | Starsindo       | X002308
4/6/12 | Starsindo       | X002408
4/6/12 | Starsindo       | X002508 
4/6/12 | Japex           | X002608
```

How to  make a query with mysql to display the names of the three expeditions that most often appear in the same date?

I just created this query, but still confused:

```
Select  * From tb_exp_expor  Order By nama_exp_expor DESC
```

Comment: what is nama_exp_expor in your query?

Comment: What are the results you expect of your query? For your example case I would expect all expedition names to be returned once, is that correct?

Comment: @praktik garg,  nama_exp_expor is mean Expedition name, sory for my mistake.

Comment: @Josien , I will make the diagram from the result of the query. and I hope the query result like this  1|Starsindo 2|De ROs indah 3|Japex, asc from the Maximal result until the Minimal Result

Comment: And what should happen if several ExpeditionNames occur the same number of times? In your example, what should the query return when there is a fourth ExpeditionNames 'NewEx' that occurs 1 time like 'Japex'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 SELECT count(*) as counta,Expedition_name,Date 
    FROM tbl_exp_expor 
    group by Expedition_name,Date
    Order by counta DESC
    limit 3
```

Comment: It Works, but the same Expedition name still not in one group, The result of query: SELECT count(*) as counta,Expedition_name,Date 
    FROM tbl_exp_expor 
    group by Expedition_name,Date
    Order by counta DESC
    limit 3

Comment: Can i have the sample data of those that is not working? Please refer to [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d634/2). The query is working for the data you attached.

Comment: oke, thanks, it work., By the way, can you tell me the php function for acsess the spesific row, ex: 5 for Starsindo it will include for pie diagram. and 3 for Ros indah. Usually i write this $data=mysql_fetch_array($sql). And for acces data i write this $data[expedtion_name]. How to write only row 2 in PHP?

Comment: @Septiyo: I think you'd best make a new question for that :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this question and answer (by [danben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217332)) on StackOverflow may help you:
[mysql: Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

It contains a link to this article:
[How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql)